# How can I create two related tables in MySQL and return a result set as JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to create two related tables in MySQL and return a result set as JSON using PHP.

I have figured out how to get my data from MySQL using PHP and how to encode it to JSON, but I'm not sure how to use Javascript to display the JSON results on my page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain what exactly the tables are for, how are they related and what output do you want in json?

Comment: What is the problem you can't handle trying to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very vague question, but here are all the pieces you'll need. Put them together in the way which solves your particular problem:

1. Basic MySQL usage example:
   https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php
2. Full MySQL documentation:
   https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php
3. Getting data from related tables:
   http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php
   (JOIN directive)
4. Encode your data in JSON:
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thanks very much...I wasn't sure where to go to get started. I've got a new job programming on the LAMP stack and its new to me as I'm a C# and .NET developer making the switch.

Comment: Well, Google is your absolute best friend... don't be afraid to just search for "php mysql" or "php json". Its what I did answering you...

Comment: Thank you very much....Now I'm off to install Ubuntu and LAMP...

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer which solves your problem!